# Execute Hadoop Command from Java app remotely

Tags: java, linux, shell, hadoop

Hi I'm triying execute any hadoop command like "hadoop fs -ls" throught a Java app remotely.
I have my Java app in my local machine and Hadoop in a VM.

First I make a ssh connection and work.
Also I can execute a linux command throught the java code but hadoop commands don´t show anything.

```
public static void testCommandJsch() throws IOException, JSchException{
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
    session.setPassword(pass);
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
    InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();
    channelExec.setCommand("hadoop fs -ls /user");
    channelExec.connect();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String linea = null;
    int index = 0;
    while ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(++index + " : " + linea);
    }
    channelExec.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
    System.out.println("------ FIN");
}
```

Any idea?